# Error in deleting files or directories older than 1 day

Tags: files, find, date, rm

I am able to delete files or directories older than 1 day using below command

```
find /u01/Release/* -mtime +1 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

but why I am getting error in the output of this command:

```
ls -lrt 
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat8 tomcat8      60 Oct  4 07:11 build_180
drwxrwxr-x 6 root    root        309 Sep 21  2017 redis-3.2.11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    1550452 Oct  4 15:23 redis-3.2.11.tar.gz

find: ‘/u01/Release/redis-3.2.11’: No such file or directory
```

after executing command

```
ls -lrt 
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat8 tomcat8      60 Oct  4 07:11 build_180
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    1550452 Oct  4 15:23 redis-3.2.11.tar.gz
```

Comment: It's not because a directory hasn't been modified in the last 10 years, that none of the files in it are recent. Modifying the content of a file doesn't modify the directory it's in. It's when you add or remove entries to/from a directory that the directory is modified. For instance `/` is hardly ever modified. You wouldn't want to remove  every file because `/` is old.

Comment: When you say _older than 1 day_, do you mean at least 2 days old (which is what `-mtime +1` checks) or more than 24 hour old?

Answer (score 2):

This is very well known issue. The problem is that `find` first removes directory and then tries to process files inside it. A solution is to first deal with stuff inside directory and only then delete directory. That's what `-depth` option is for, so:

```
find /u01/Release/* -depth -mtime +1 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

should do the trick. You may also be interested in the shorter form using `-delete` action (which implies `-depth`):

```
find /u01/Release/* -mtime +1 -delete
```

As always `man find` is your friend.

Comment: It's `-mtime +0` for files older than 24 hours

Comment: Note that when you remove a file from a directory, that updates its mtime. If `a/b/c` is 1 minute old, `a/b` 5 days old and `a` 5 year old, then it will remove `a/b` (and `c` in the process), but not `a`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, sure, I bet star glob is most probably also not what OP needs, but that's other topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, Better to use `--force` which will delete files and directories.

```
find /u01/Release/* -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;


-r, -R, --recursive
              remove directories and their contents recursively
-f, --force
                  ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
```

Comment: i tried that but still get this message find: ‘/u01/Release/redis-3.2.11’: No such file or directory

Comment: ok, that means no older files are available under the directory `/u01/Release/redis-3.2.11`

Comment: `/u01/Release/redis-3.2.11` this is older directory. it is deleting that directory with that message

Comment: share the `ls -d /u01/Release/redis-3.2.11` output here